# Docusign - How to sort envelope form data? Using C# SDK EnvelopeAPI.GetEnvelopeFormData

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Is there any way to sort the form data by label creation date or by by the placement of the label in the envelope? Based on the documentation in [get envelopeFormData](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeFormData/get/) it seems like no option exists. I am trying to sort the response form data by appearance in the envelope template, but the sdk alone only provides form label name and form label value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in the SDK for what you are trying to achieve. Separate tag creation/update is not traced. What you can do is to make a call to [get single envelope](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/get/) which will return "lastModifiedDateTime" but this is date for the last change made to the envelope. I hope this will help a little bit

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information from the `ListRecipents` endpoint, but you will need to construct it by yourself if you want to the doc.

The endpoint gives you info about the envelope like: `signers, agents, editors`. The information you need is stored in the `textTabs` array and you'll need to pass `include_tabs=true` as param to the endpoint and the response will include info like:
`value pageNumber xPosition yPosition anchorString anchorUnits`

The ListRecipients endpoint looks like this:
`/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients`

For e.g if you want to get all the fields in order for signers it will be in
`signers[0].tabs.textTabs`

More info in the docs here with all options available: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/list/